# JavaScript for loop object replace undefined and assign value for non-existing keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object called `data` some of the elements are `undefined`, or simply missing.

How can I do a `for` loop to assign my personal value to these fields?

```
data.forEach(function(obj) {
  for(var i in obj) { 
    if(obj[i] === undefined) {
      obj[i] = '';
    }
  }
});
```

This is currently only replacing the `undefined`, how can I update to pass an empty value for any field if it doesn't exist?

Comment: where do you want it to pull the keys from? Do you have, like, an array of keys you want this object to have?

Comment: There's no way of telling, from the code you're showing, what keys do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with all your keys:

```
var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'buzz'];
```

then iterate over it and check for that is key-given property exists in your object

```
var obj = {
    foo: 'a'
}

for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];

    if (!obj[key]) {
        obj[key] = '';
    }      
}
```

Cheers

Comment: "for of" is not supported in my javascript version. could you please modify it?

Comment: `for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; i++) { console.log(keys[i]); }` ;)

Comment: so could you please update your answer with this new modification?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to complete the "gaps", in the sense that some of your objects will not have properties that others do have, then you can use this ES6 code:

```js
function fillGaps(data) {
    return new Set([].concat(...data.map(Object.keys))) // create set of all keys
        .forEach( key =>
            data.filter( obj => obj[key] === undefined) // get missing/undefined keys
                .forEach( obj => obj[key] = '' ) ); // set them
}

// Example
var data = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    a: 10,
    b: 30,
    c: 9
}, {
    a: undefined,
    c: 8
}];

fillGaps(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### ES5 equivalent

```js
function fillGaps(data) {
    // create object with all keys
    keys = Object.keys([].concat.apply([], data.map(Object.keys))
                    .reduce (function (acc, key) {
                        acc[key] = 1;
                        return acc;
                    }, {})
    ).forEach(function (key) {
        return data.filter(function (obj) { // get missing/undefined keys
            return obj[key] === undefined;
        }).forEach(function (obj) {  // set them
            obj[key] = '';
        });
    });
}

// Example
var data = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    a: 10,
    b: 30,
    c: 9
}, {
    a: undefined,
    c: 8
}];

fillGaps(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks, although this is working in absolute, by my "data" is an argument of one of my functions, and i get it as in input, so i need to treat it inside my function only.... however I can't then include your function inside it..

Comment: What is the problem with that? Either just grab the code from inside my proposed function (`new Set( .... `) or put the function in your code, and call it from within your current function. Even if you place my function *inside* your function, and then call it, it should work.